Merkle Patricia Trie pad and prefix concept
I understand <> it is used for empty slots, rootHash is 16 for hex. and hashB placed 5th position because of '4', but how does perhaps padding work? i.e. in hashA: 20, hashB: 00, hashE: <17>, [<35>]
I read some existing solutions but not quite related to this problem. I hope you can help me.
Problem:
<64 6f> : 'verb'
<64 6f 67> : 'puppy'
<64 6f 67 65> : 'coin'
<68 6f 72 73 65> : 'stallion'

Answer:
rootHash: [ <16>, hashA ]
hashA:    [ <>, <>, <>, <>, hashB, <>, <>, <>, [ <20 6f 72 73 65>, 'stallion' ], <>, <>, <>, <>, <>, <>, <>, <> ]
hashB:    [ <00 6f>, hashD ]
hashD:    [ <>, <>, <>, <>, <>, <>, hashE, <>, <>, <>, <>, <>, <>, <>, <>, <>, 'verb' ]
hashE:    [ <17>, [ <>, <>, <>, <>, <>, <>, [ <35>, 'coin' ], <>, <>, <>, <>, <>, <>, <>, <>, <>, 'puppy' ] ]

src: https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/data-structures-and-encoding/patricia-merkle-trie/#example-trie

The answer is in this page too, just above the code you posted.
It is called COMPACT encoding, whose implementation located in go-ethereum/trie/encoding.go.
In hashA: 20, hashB: 00, hashE: <17>, [<35>], they have been handled by compact_encode function shown on the page too.
